# Get time zone abbreviation using POSIX (Perl)

Tags: perl, cgi

I would like to know if it's possible to get the time zone abbreviation (example: EST, CST, PST) by simply using POSIX ? I can get the full time zone name (example: Pacific Standard Time) by using POSIX with the following code:

```
use POSIX;
print strftime("%Z", localtime()), "\n";
```

I know there are modules available for date/time manipulation but since I only need to get the time zone abbreviation, I would like to avoid using a big module just for that.

Comment: If you can, avoid relying on these abbreviations because they are not unique and have no semblance of a standards body governing them. Use the [zoneinfo](http://enwp.org/zoneinfo) names (e.g. Europe/Vienna) or RFC 3339 offsets (e.g. +0200) instead.

Comment: In my case it shows the short version, EST, using perl 5.8.8

Comment: The Perl version does not matter, but the underlying OS/libc. AFAICT Linux gives the abbreviation. The [docs](http://p3rl.org/POSIX#strftime) already clearly state that `%Z` *inter alia* is not portable.

Comment: The abbreviations are not standard, so you could roll your own: `print strftime("%Z",localtime)=~/([A-Z])/g`

Comment: Just tested the script under Linux and Win2003 Server and I get different values (like Cornel Ghiban mentioned). I guess I will have to take a look at the various Perl modules available.  I know DateTime is known as the best module for date/time manipulation but it's huge and depends on several other modules.  Thanks everyone.

Comment: At the least you could add the timezone offset as a further differentiator: perl -le 'print strftime "%Z %z",localtime'

Comment: DateTime is large because it takes care of a lot of edge cases - i.e. it does things right, and time calculations are not simple. :)

Answer (score 3):

Time zone databases are not part of the POSIX (or any other Unix) standard. To properly handle time zones you need a time zone database, such as the [Olson database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database).

In Perl, you can use the [DateTime](http://datetime.perl.org) module which together with [DateTime::TimeZone](http://p3rl.org/DateTime%3a%3aTimeZone) module will give you access to that database. Again, using such databases is the **only** way to properly handle time zones.

Comment: Thanks Daniel Ruoso.

I've installed the DateTime module and I must say that I'm really disappointed.  The module is depending on 956 files (.pm) and doesn't even have all the cities in there.  I can get the time for major cities like New York  but there's no data available for smaller cities. No luck for even getting the time for a city like Seattle.

Comment: You're misunderstanding something. The purpose of the Olson DB is not to catalogue every city in the world, but to define time zones as they existed at certain points of time, these are assigned regional names instead of e.g. arbitrary numeric identifiers simply because it's easier for humans. You are supposed to deduce on your own that Seattle falls under America/Los_Angeles, or employ some geographical code such as [Geo::Location::TimeZone](http://p3rl.org/Geo::Location::TimeZone).